# Matching IPA font for Charter

Tags: fonts, tipa

How could I get a phonetic font compile with `charter` package?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{charter,tipa,lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
[\textipa{D}]
\end{document}
```

Then the characters in brackets are still CM fonts.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: May be Charis SIL characters? You will need XeLaTeX…

Comment: @juncly I don't understand the question. That will compile fine? Are you asking for a phonetic font which will work well with Charter? If so, could you edit your question to clarify that because right now the answer to your question is 'just run latex on it and it will compile'.

Comment: juncly wants to be able to type phonetic characters in the same typeface as the font provided by the ``charter`` package.